# Invalid pointer in C

Tags: c, struct

I apologize in advance, but this is kind of a long one.

In my program, I read in the student's information, but when I go to output it, it comes out scrambled, and then gets a pointer error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student{
        char *firstName;
        char *lastName;
        char id[10];
        char gender;
        int age;
        double gpa;
};

void main()
{
    int n;
    struct student *classroom;

    printf("How many students?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    classroom = (struct student*) malloc(n*sizeof(struct student));

    if (classroom == NULL)
    exit(1);

readStudentsInformation(classroom,n);
outputStudents(classroom,n);
printf("The average age is %.2f.\n",averageAge(classroom,n));
printf("The average GPA is %.2f.\n",averageGpa(classroom,n));
sortByLastName(classroom,n);
outputStudents(classroom,n);
sortByID(classroom,n);
outputStudents(classroom,n);
sortByAge(classroom,n);
}

void outputStudents(struct student classroom[], int size)
{

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%15s",classroom[i].firstName);
        printf("%15s:",classroom[i].lastName);
        printf("%14s,",classroom[i].id);
        printf("%3c",classroom[i].gender);
        printf("%5d",classroom[i].age);
        printf("%5.2f",classroom[i].gpa);
    }
}
```

Input:
   How many students?2
   First Name?Thom
   Last Name?Arron
   ID?2
   Gender?M
   Age?26
   GPA?3.9
   First Name?Frank
   Last Name?Roberts
   ID?1
   Gender?F
   Age?24
   GPA?3.4'

Output:

```
    Roberts        Roberts:             2,  M   26 3.90                              :             1,  F   24 3.40The average age is 25.00.
```

The average GPA is 3.65.
*** glibc detected *** ./lab12: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff30319a90 ***

```
                       :             2,  M   26 3.90Aborted (core dumped)
```

The full code is here, but I didn't want to copy 200 lines to stack overflow: http://codepad.org/LYpS6t5z

Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: `munmap_chunk` sounds like part of `free`, which means you probably corrupted `malloc`'d memory.

Comment: looks like you're doing weird stuff with _temp_ and your member pointers [which is leaking mallocd memory at a minimum and will segfault when you come to free the members]

Comment: valgrind is real good at finding these problems.

Comment: @amdixon weird stuff?

Comment: @Kevin How do you suppose that happened?

Comment: You trampled over memory that you did not allocate. Like writing past the end of an array. Compile with -g and then run valgrind. It will tell you the line where you run off the end of something.

Comment: By weird stuff i mean assigning a stack reference to those pointers [and in the process leaking all possibility of freeing your malloc memory]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one conceptual error, you have it in a couple of places

```
classroom[i].firstName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1+strlen(temp)));
if (classroom[i].firstName == NULL)
     exit(1);
classroom[i].firstName = temp;
```

What you want here instead is

```
classroom[i].firstName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1+strlen(temp)));
if (classroom[i].firstName == NULL)
     exit(1);
strcpy(classroom[i].firstName, temp); // note this
```

Or, cleaned up a bit:

```
classroom[i].firstName = malloc(1+strlen(temp)); // note clean up here
if (classroom[i].firstName == NULL)
     exit(1);
strcpy(classroom[i].firstName, temp);
```

Or even just

```
classroom[i].firstName = strdup(temp); // this takes place of all the lines above
```

These errors explain why your free's are failing.

Nothing else jumps out at me.

Comment: `strcmp` compares, you want `strcpy`.

Comment: Oh, you're right, except that I want strcpy. I forgot to change that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
classroom[i].firstName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1+strlen(temp)));
if (classroom[i].firstName == NULL)
    exit(1);
classroom[i].firstName = temp;
```

Your second assignment here overwrites the *address*, leaking the `malloc`d memory and making the pointer invalid as soon as that `for` iteration finishes. The same buffer is reused (with the same error) for `lastName`, which is why you see  `Roberts    Roberts` instead of the actual first and last name. When you go to `free` them, they are (1) invalid and (2) not made by `malloc`, so you get the crash you see.

Just like other arrays, you can't copy them by assignment, you have to copy byte-by-byte:

```
size_t len = strlen(temp);
classroom[i].firstName = malloc(1+len);
if (classroom[i].firstName == NULL)
    exit(1);
strncpy(classroom[i].firstname, temp, len);
classroom[i].firstname[len] = '\0';
```

And don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Weirdness happening in *readStudentsInformation*, in particular lines like

`classroom[i].lastName = temp;`

are causing issues later on when you try to free this memory with

`free(classroom[i].firstName);`

Appropriate memory handling below:

```
void readStudentsInformation(struct student classroom[], int size)
{
  int i;
  char temp[50];

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf("First Name?");
    scanf("%s",temp);
    classroom[i].firstName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1+strlen(temp)));
    if (classroom[i].firstName == NULL)
      exit(1);
    /* after mallocing good memory can write in the data.. */
    strcpy(classroom[i].firstName, temp);
/*    classroom[i].firstName = temp; */
    printf("Last Name?");
    scanf("%s",temp);
    classroom[i].lastName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1+strlen(temp)));
    if (classroom[i].lastName == NULL)
      exit(1);
/*    classroom[i].lastName = temp; */
    strcpy(classroom[i].lastName, temp);
    printf("ID?");
    scanf("%s",classroom[i].id);
    fflush(stdin);
    __fpurge(stdin);
    printf("Gender?");
    scanf("%c",&classroom[i].gender);
    printf("Age?");
    scanf("%d",&classroom[i].age);
    printf("GPA?");
    scanf("%lf",&classroom[i].gpa);
  }
}
```